# Realizar un UNION con Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hola buenas como puedo realizar un UNION en codeigniter ya que deseo que en mi arreglo me entre las dos tablas. 
Algo asi por el estilo.

```
[array] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                //TABLA 1
                    [id_tecnico] => 1698
                    [fecha] => 2018-02-12
                    [NroSolicitud] => M49320
                    [horaInicio] => 15:15
                    [horaTermino] => 17:45
                    [Comentario] => se repara bastidor .ok.
                    [total] => 2.5
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                 //TABLA 2
                [id_tecnico] => 1698
                [NroSolicitud] => M49317
                [fecha] => 2018-02-12
                [actividad] => Reunion
                [Comentario] => reunion de trabajo
                [TotalHrs] => 0.67
                )
          )
```

tengo la siguiente query en mi modelo, donde realizo la query a la tabla `Mantenciones`, pero deseo hacer tambien una consulta a la tabla `Actividades` con los mismos `WHERE`

--Actualizo la query del modelo y muestro los resultados.

```
$this->db->select('p.Nombre,s.fecha,s.NroSolicitud,d.horaInicio,d.horaTermino,d.Comentario,d.total,m.maquina');
   $this->db->from('Tecnico_Seguimiento as t');
   $this->db->join('personal as p','p.Codigo = t.id_tecnico');
   $this->db->join('MAN_SeguimientoDetalle as d','d.id_detalle = t.id_detalle');
   $this->db->join('MAN_Seguimiento as s','s.idMan_Tecnico = d.id_man_tecnico');
   $this->db->join('MAN_Solicitud as m','m.NroSolicitud = s.NroSolicitud');

   $this->db->where('t.id_tecnico',$id);
   $this->db->where('s.fecha >=',$minvalue);
   $this->db->where('s.fecha <=',$maxvalue);

   $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();


   $this->db->select('act.NroSolicitud as NroAct, act.fecha as fechaAct,act.actividad,act.Comentario, act.TotalHrs, act.orden, act.horaActividad, act.id_tecnico ');
   $this->db->from('MAN_Actividades as act');
   $this->db->where('act.fecha >=',$minvalue);
   $this->db->where('act.fecha <=',$maxvalue);
   $this->db->where('act.id_tecnico <=',$id);
   $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
   return $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2)->result();
```

Con esta query obtengo estos valores

```
[seguimientos] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Nombre] => CABALLERO HUGO
                [fecha] => 2018-02-20
                [NroSolicitud] => M49301
                [horaInicio] => 17:45
                [horaTermino] => 19:30
                [Comentario] => cambio de valvula .ok.
                [total] => 1.75
                [maquina] => Torno
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
            //Aqui deberia ser los campos de la tabla actividades
                [Nombre] => M49321
                [fecha] => 2018-02-12
                [NroSolicitud] => Reunion
                [horaInicio] => reunion de trabajo
                [horaTermino] => 1
                [Comentario] => 49321
                [total] => 17:43:00
                [maquina] => 1698
            )
 )
```

En vez de `[NroSolicitud] => Reunion` deberia ser `[actividad] => Reunion`

Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: No se sobre este lenguaje... pero lo raro es tratar de unir dos tablas que no tienen relacion alguna entre ellas.. cual seria el sentido de esto? UNION se usa para unir dos tablas que comparten una relacion entre las columnas de ellas...

Comment: en ambas tabla guardo la `ID` del trabajador y pregunto en ambas tablas por la `ID` y entre fechas

Comment: Pero eso no tiene nada que ver... aunque sea en una union, vas a hacer dos consultas. no hay diferencia por mas que sea union...

Comment: Creo que union solo te coge los datos que son iguales. Por lo que deberas probar otra cosa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que te sirva, te lo ilustro con una imágenes primero de la **UNION** desde MYSQL.

paso1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
paso2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo CodeIgniter

```
class Union_model extends CI_Model {

    public function getUnion($actividad){
        $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT id_tecnico,fecha,NroSolicitud,horaInicio,horaTermino,Comentario,total,'' as Actividad, '' TotalHrs FROM tabla1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id_tecnico,'' as fecha,NroSolicitud,'' as horaInicio,'' as horaTermino,Comentario,'' as total, Actividad, TotalHrs FROM tabla2 ) AS Mantenciones
        WHERE actividad =".$actividad);
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```